# Keeping track of destroyed objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, events, destroy

I searched stack-overflow for similar approaches and didn't find anything so here goes my question:

I need to be able to keep track if a destroy has happened on a object and the time it happened.
I also don't really need the whole object just the id it had.

Is there a gem that does this or do it need to handle this in my database?

Comment: If you don't *mind* keeping the records around, you could use the paranoia gem, which adds a `deleted_at` timestamp and scopes the models using it so deleted records are excluded by default: https://github.com/radar/paranoia.

Comment: Thank you, i think this method is the best for me.

Comment: In that case I'll add this as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't *mind* keeping the records around, you could use the [paranoia gem](https://github.com/radar/paranoia), which adds a `deleted_at` timestamp and scopes the models using it so deleted records are excluded by default.

Answer (score 4):

The [observer pattern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html) should be used for that.

You need to create a model which observes your model:

```
class AuditObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  observe :account

  def after_destroy(account)
    p "#{account.id} destroyed"
  end
end
```

Here the `AuditObserver` observes the `Account` model and prints out the message if an account has been destroyed.

Keep in mind, that you need to add your observers to your configuration (`config/appplication.rb`) as:

```
config.active_record.observers = :audit_observer
```

#### Update

If you want to have the destroyed objects for a certain period, you can use the [rails3_acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/rails3_acts_as_paranoid) gem.

Then you can fetch the deleted accounts as:

```
Account.deleted_after_time(time)
```

Or you can create a new model (`Audit`) and you can insert the destroyed ids with the timestamp into that table.

Comment: Is it possible to get all Account's ids that have been destroyed after a certain time?